# Add Vertical Scroll To Content Section JQM

Tags: jquery-mobile

How can you add vertical scrolling to the content section of a jquery mobile site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean with the [header and footer fixed](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed.html)? Or perhaps something like [iscroll](https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll), if that then there is a [plug-in wrapper](https://github.com/watusi/jquery-mobile-iscrollview) for JQM for that plug in. If it's not fixed headers and footers your after then you should be able to just stick a div with a height specified and style it to have scroll bars.

Comment: yes I want fixed headers and footers. Some of my pages have content that seems under the footer. I need to scroll the content section so users can see all the data

Comment: Is there a reason why the built in JQM method for fixed headers/footers isn't good (that is by adding `data-position="fixed"` to your header & footer)?

Comment: I have that added to my header and footer but the content doesnt all show up in the content view it runs behind the footer

Comment: I think the plug-in that I linked to accomplishes what you are trying to achieve, I don't know if there is an online demo of it but you can easily download the demo and open it in a browser to see if that is what you are looking for.